# Combining filters with vainilla JS, issue with logic

Tags: javascript

I'm practising with DOM manipulation, APIs and filters; I am creating a table with JavaScript, I've created some checkboxes and a drop-down to filter the data, and now trying to combining both.

So far, I managed to make it work for 3 out of the 4 possible cases, but I don't see what I am missing on the fourth.

This my filtering function:

```
function filtering(data, optionChecked, harvestTypeValue) {
  let filteredResults = [];
  if (optionChecked.length === 0 && harvestTypeValue === 'all') {
    // No checkboxes checked and dropdown with option "All" selected. Working
    filteredResults = data
  } else if (optionChecked.length === 0 && harvestTypeValue != 'all') {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i]['Harvest Type'] == harvestTypeValue) {
        // No checkboxes checked and dropdown with any option selected. Working:
        filteredResults.push(data[i]);
      }
    }
  } else if (optionChecked.length != 0 && harvestTypeValue === 'all') {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (optionChecked.includes(data[i]['NOAA Fisheries Region'])) {
        // Any checkbox checked and dropdown with All. Working:
        filteredResults.push(data[i]);
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (filteredResults.includes(data[i]['NOAA Fisheries Region']) && data[i]['Harvest Type'] == harvestTypeValue) {
        // Any/some checkboxes checked and dropdown with any option selected. NOT working.
        // Getting an empty object:
        filteredResults.push(data[i]); 
      }
    }
  }
  createTable(filteredResults)
}
```

It might be a small thing, or a big fail in my logic, but I am clueless and almost giving up.

I would also appreciate any suggestions to make that code shorter.

Comment: Can you update the code to show how you're calling the function? What are the arguments that you're providing?

Comment: i didn't want to post all my code to avoid a long chunk of confusing lines. How do people usually do it here? maybe posting a codepen link or similar?

Comment: The trick is to post enough code that we can reproduce your problem, and see what's happening; if you read the "*[mcve]*" guidance it should help. If you feel you'll be posting a long chunk of confusing lines then that's a sign that you need to tidy up your code a little, and strip out the parts that don't contribute to the problem (often, this can help you realise what the problem is).

Comment: thanks for the tip! i am reading it now. I'll try to do it. 
In this case , by confusing , I was more thinking that there are a lot of lines to create DOm element, attributes, classes, later to add the eventlisteners, etc... that might make the code look to long and boring for anyone to give it a look. (and of course, for expert eyes might be also ugly to see, i don't know) 

I'll see if i can replicate it in a simpler way

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica , thanks a lot for your editing work.
I will try to pay more attention to those things in the future.

Answer (score 1):

last Else , instead of

```
if (filteredResults.includes(data[i]['NOAA Fisheries Region']) && data[i]['Harvest Type'] == harvestTypeValue)
```

should be :

```
if (optionChecked.includes(data[i]['NOAA Fisheries Region']) && data[i]['Harvest Type'] == harvestTypeValue)
```

Now it makes sense and both filters work combined in all possible ways

amazing how blind (and stupid) I was...

Thanks to all!